# My Insertion sort algorithm leaves larger number unsorted

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort the following list (which gets inserted to the a array):
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
After the below java code executes I get the following (not sure why the largest number is still unsorted, thanks in advance for any help you can provide):
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I'm basically implementing the java code from the following pseudocode from a text book:

```
procedure insertionsort(a1, a2, ...an: real numbers with n>=2)
for j:=2 to n
begin
i:=1
while a[j]>a[i]
  i=:i+1

temp:=a[j]

for k:=0 to j - i - 1
 a[j-k] := a[j-k-1]

a[i]:=temp
end
```

java code:

```
int k, j,i;  
long temp;

for(j=2; j<nElems; j++)   
{
   i=1;  

   //also tried while(a[j]>=a[i]) 
   while(a[j]>a[i]) 
       i = i +1;         

   temp = a[j];            
   for(k=0; k<=(j-i-1);k++)  
         a[j-k] = a[j-k-1];

   a[i] = temp;                 
}// end for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the pseudocode array is 1-based, while Java arrays are 0-based.

Just change

```
for (j=2; j<nElems; j++) {
    i=1;
    // more code
```

to

```
for (j=1; j<nElems; j++) {
    i=0;
    // more code
```

Answer (score 2):

In the pseudocode, the array index seems to start from **"1"** whereas, in Java, array index starts from **"0"**.

Change the code to:

```
public class InsertionSort{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int k,j,i,n=5;  
        long a[]={1025,3689,125,12,254},temp;


        for(j=1; j<n; j++) // instead of j=2
        {
            i=0; // instead of i=1
            while(a[j]>a[i]) 
                i = i+1;         
            temp = a[j];            

            for(k=0; k<=(j-i-1);k++)  
                a[j-k] = a[j-k-1];

            a[i] = temp;                 
        }  // end for

        for(long x:a){
            System.out.print(x+" ");
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:** `12 125 254 1025 3689`